# RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in double_scalars numpy

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I made a python script that makes a linear regression using numpy.
When I run them I am getting the following error:

> Warning (from warnings module):
>   File "C:\Users\Moham\Desktop\Simple linear regression.py", line 27
>   gradient_sum_squares += gradient ** 2
>   RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in double_scalars

Any help on what is wrong would be highly appreciated.

Here's the code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from math import sqrt

df = pd.read_csv('Boston.csv')

def simple_linear_regression(x_points, y_points, step_size=0.01, tolerance=0.001, max_iter=1000):



 converged = False
    coefficients = np.random.rand(2)
    y = np.array(y_points)
    X = np.ones((len(x_points), 2))
    X[:, 1] = x_points
    iteration = 0

    while not converged:

        if iteration >= max_iter:
            return coefficients

        predictions = np.dot(X, coefficients)
        residual = y - predictions
        gradient_sum_squares = 0

        for i in range(len(coefficients)):
            gradient = np.dot(2, np.dot(X[:, i], residual))
            gradient_sum_squares += gradient ** 2
            coefficients[i] = coefficients[i] - np.dot(step_size, gradient)

        if sqrt(gradient_sum_squares) < tolerance:
            converged = True

        iteration += 1

    return coefficients

print(simple_linear_regression(df["TV"], df["sales"]))
```